# Implicit/Backward Euler for DAE

Tags: matlab, differential-equations, implicit-methods

I have a question regarding implicit Euler. I know how to compute implicit Euler method but my problem is how to use it on DAE ( differential algebraic equation). I obtained a correct solution after I applied index reduction on my original DAE and thus I obtained ODE and then I applied my implicit Euler. However, the task was to deploy implicit Euler on DAE. Can anyone give me a hint on how to improve my code so it works for DAE also? Thanks a lot and please see my code attached.

[image]

Here is my solution for the problem:

```
[t,y]=beul('system','dsystem',[-1,1,-1],0,1,100);
plot(t,y);

function yp=system(t,y)
yp(2)=y(1);  % equations
yp(3)=y(2);
yp(1)=exp(-t);  % after applying index reduction we obtain this
end

function y=dsystem(t,x)
y(1,1)=-1;
y(1,2)=0;
y(1,3)=0;
y(2,1)=0;
y(2,2)=-1;
y(2,3)=0;
y(3,1)=0;
y(3,2)=0;
y(3,3)=-1;


end

function [t,y]=beul(f,df,y0,t0,tf,n)
h=(tf-t0)/n;
t=linspace(t0,tf,n+1);
y=zeros(n+1,length(y0));
y(1,:)=y0;
for i=1:n
k0=y(i,:)';
k1=k0-inv(eye(length(y0))-h*feval(df,t(i),k0))*(k0-h*feval(f,t(i),k0)'-y(i,:)');
while (norm(k1-k0)>0.0001) % Newton evaluation
k0=k1;
k1=k0-inv(eye(length(y0))-h*feval(df,t(i),k0))*(k0-h*feval(f,t(i),k0)'-y(i,:)');
end
y(i+1,:)=k1;
end
end
```

Comment: How automatic should the solver work? Can you just solve the equations for implicit Euler manually, i.e., `x3[k+1]=-u3[k+1], x2[k+1]=(x3[k+2]-x3[k])/h, x1[k+1]=(x2[k+1]-x2[k])/h` or has that to be derived automatically from the input equations?

Answer (score 0):

The `ode15s` and `ode23t` solvers can solve index-1 linearly implicit problems with a singular mass matrix.
[MATLAB: Solve Differential Algebraic Equations (DAEs)](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/solve-differential-algebraic-equations-daes.html)